# Is it possible to read text files from Azure Blob storage from the end?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have rather large blob files that I need to read and ingest only latest few rows of information from.  Is there an API (C#) that would read the files from the end until I want to stop, so that my app ingests the minimum information possible?

Comment: One quick question .... Can you tell us if each record inserted in blob is of fixed length? In other words, does each row is of fixed size or it can vary? Is there some structure to your record in the blob file.

Comment: There is structure, but record length maybe different (ie certain fields are variable length)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respectfully, I disagree with the answer. While it is true that Page Blobs are designed for random access, they are meant for different purpose all together.

I also agree that Block Blobs are designed for sequential access, however nothing is preventing you from reading a block blob's content from the middle. With the support for range reads in block blob, it is entirely possible for you to read partial contents of a block blob.

To give you an example, let's assume you have a 10 MB blob (blob size = 10485760 bytes). Now you want to read the blob from the bottom. Assuming you want to read 1MB chunk at a time, you would call [`DownloadRangeToByteArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadrangetobytearray.aspx) or `DownloadRangeToStream` (or their Async variants) and specify `9437184` (9MB marker) as starting range and `10485759` (10MB marker) as ending range. Read the contents and see if you find what you're looking for. If not, you can read blob's contents from 8MB to 9MB and continue with the process.

Comment: your assumption is that you know in advance the blob's size. otherwise, you need to issue a separate call to get the blob size before calculating the offset.

Answer (score 4):

You should already know that BlockBlobs are designed for `sequential` access, while Page Blobs are designed for `random` access. And AppendBlobs for Append operations, which in your case is not what we are looking for.

I believe your solution would be to save your blobs as `PageBlob` as opposed the default `BlockBlob`. Once you have a Page Blob, you have nice methods like [GetPageRangesAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451512.aspx) which returns an IEnbumerable of [PageRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.pagerange.aspx). The latter overrides [ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.pagerange.tostring.aspx) method to give you the string content of the page.